# Calling function returns [Function: name] - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm writting a small game for a challenge and wrote a function that initializes the game by picking a phrase based on a random number.  When I'm calling the function console.log(initialize) the console is just returning [Function: initialize]

What am I doing wrong here?

```
function initialize() {
  var ph_1 = ['i', ' ', 'l','o','v','e',' ','l','a','m','p']
  var ph_2 = ['m','i','l','k',' ','w','a','s',' ','a',' ','b','a','d',' ','c','h','o','i','c','e']
  var ph_3 = ['i','','a','m','','k','i','n','d','','o','f','','a','','b','i','g','','d','e','a','l']

  switch(Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1)) {
    case 1:
      var phrase = ph_1
      break;
    case 2:
      var phrase = ph_2
      break;
    case 3:
      var phrase = ph_3
      break;
   }
   return phrase;
}


// Driver Tests
console.log(initialize);
```

JS v0.10.32

Comment: You are passing the function, not calling it. To call a function you have to use `()` after the function reference, like so: `foo()`.

Comment: console.log(initialize())

Comment: oh my...that explains it. Just corrected that in my console and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a better way to do what I'm doing, overall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

errr, I was calling the function improperly by missing the paren after initialize - should be

```
console.log(initialize());
```

Thank you @Felix_king

Answer (score 1):

For calling function you should use `()` construction and so you should use like this:

```
console.log(initialize());
```